# Is there a way to prove that a nintendo 3ds game is not new?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have bought a nintendo 3ds game from an online shop. The descriptions said that the product was new and precinted. Unfortunately when I received it, it was without precint of any kind and it was open.

Is there a way to prove (or even to check) that this game was used before I received?

There were not saved games when I first tried it but I think that maybe the game card keeps record of saved games even when they are deleted.

Comment: Well, unless you can see exactly how old it was, the game is not new anymore because you tried to see if there were savegames on it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If by Precint you mean it did not come with the box and manual and case or what not... Then yeah, this was not new.

Comment: Now is not new because I used it of course :). But I'm wondering if there is a way to prove that the first time I used it was before I bought it.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe in the game card there is a record of 'first usage' with a timestamp or a table recording each time the game is played.

Comment: AFAIK there is no date record on 3DS cartridges. I opened a few of them on a modded 3DS, and the dates of all files inside are shown as `1980-01-01`. It doesn't prevent a particular game from saving the timestamp somewhere of course, but this will be strictly game-specific.